# JBoss Fuse Integration from HTTP with POST parameters

Tags: jboss, jbossfuse

Firstly, apologies as I'm a bit of an ESB newbie.

I'm trying use `Fuse Integration` in `Red Hat JBoss Developer Studio` to create a simple integration between an HTTP URL with some POST parameters (login, password, etc) to an output file.

I'm thinking I'd need to carry out the following steps...

1. Do a HTTP login to a specified URL (passing login, password as parameters)
2. Capture authentication details - cookie file? - to reuse for the next step
3. Do a HTTP fetch from the same URL
4. Write the fetched data to a text file

A colleague's making some progress with this using Mulesoft but I'd like to see if this is a simpler exercise in JBoss.

Comment: Something like this example might get you going [Camel Jetty Client IP](https://github.com/tmielke/fuse-demos/tree/master/Camel/Camel-Jetty-Client-IP) or this [Hello Camel](https://github.com/FuseByExample/HelloCamel) basically you likely want to use the Jetty component, you'll have to hack around a bit to get at the cookie likely but with camel and endpoints, you may not need to, after the login you might be able to do a camel route to the other page that you want to fetch the data from and write it to a file which would be another camel route